# How to calculate the spatial frequency of an image in cycles per image

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, spatial

I have been attempting to calculate the spatial frequency of a colour image.

I first converted it to grayscale and used a Fast Fourier transformation (fft2) that codes the quantity of each spatial frequency in the image in MATLAB. This provides a matrix of coefficients representing the amount of each spatial frequency and orientation and its phase.

I’m having difficulty translating this matrix into a spatial frequency value that I can use to describe the spatial frequency of the image in cycles per image. Also, how can I plot the fft in a way that shows the cycles?

Do you have any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: fftshift , then , imshow(log10(abs(fftshif))

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, you cannot convert a whole matrix into a single spatial frequency value. The resulting matrix tells you, at a given distance from the centre of the matrix (assuming that you `fftshift`ed the matrix) and with a certain orientation (based on the angle with the centre) what is the strength of that frequency.

Regarding the second question, I am quoting @MimSaad answer `fftshift, then, imshow(log10(abs(fftshift))` where `log10` is used to reduce the discrepancies between the very strongly and the very weakly present frequencies; and `abs` is used to get the strength of that frequency (which is otherwise coded as a complex number).